# JIRA-BDD-Specflow Test Management tool add in

Tags: jenkins, jira, bdd, specflow

We are using JIRA, SpecFlow, Jenkins in our project.

Can anybody tell us a tool that can be used as JIRA add in to organize, maintain, and track the testing process, progress, and results of execution the test scenarios in the BDD Feature files?

I want to record and track both the manual tests my team will run and all the automated tests generated through BDD Feature files in JIRA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used BehavePro which worked excellent. The business could create the user stories in Gherkin and we would export it to Visual Studio and automate the tests.

Besides that I have no experience in other tools/plugins.

Comment: Hi Anand, Thanks for your suggestion. Could you please explain me how the BDD test cases from JIRA are exported to Visual Studio please. Thanks